# Speech Synthesis API blocks main thread

Tags: javascript, multithreading, text-to-speech

I am using the  Speech Synthesis API to pronounce a list of different words. My app animates the words in and out as they're being spoken via canvas. I realized that when I perform a new utterance:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(word);
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

the spoken word appears to block the main thread, temporarily stalling the animation. This happens every time I call `window.speechSynthesis.speak();`.

Is there a way to have the speech synthesis run on a separate thread in Javascript, so it doesn't interfere with my animation on the main thread?

(I am primarily testing this in Chrome)

Comment: Here is [a simple jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/0oLbmy56/4/) with an animation and speech synthetis. Can you modify it to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a setTimeout to fake an asynchronious call:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(word);
setTimeout(function() { window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg); }, 1);
```

I must admit I'm not sure about this.

Comment: This didn't work for me, which I think makes sense. Just because you move the function to be processed at the end of the current event loop, the function is still processed IN the main thread, which means that if the function is a long running function, (even if it's a in timeout) it will still run in the main thread, thus *will* still lag.

Comment: Yeah I think you've hit the nail on the head @AlexMorley-Finch. This doesn't really work, not sure why it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to follow here would be to use a worker thread that plays the audio corresponding to the text message.

A web-worker, however doesnot have access to the window object. So we cannot call the `window.speechSythesis.speak` method directly inside the worker.

A nice work around which [text-to-speech library from Francois Laberge](https://github.com/francoislaberge/texttospeech) implements is

1. Send the text to be spoken to the worker thread.
2. The worker thread would then convert this text to an audio(WAV) file and return the main-thread the WAV file.
3. The main thread on receiving a message from the worker thread will run the WAV file using an audio element.

In my opinion for even a better performance a worker pool can be created.

Please have a look at the demo [here](http://francoislaberge.com/texttospeech/demo.html)

Comment: This is an interesting solution! I briefly considered web workers too, but dismissed it because it wouldn't have access to the speech synthesis API. Wonder how good this is compared to native implementations?

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest you to see this lovely summary of Philip Roberts about what is the **event loop** and why `setTimeout` 0 makes sense: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

In short a quick solution may be what Booster2ooo says, that you wrap the call within a setTimeout call:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg); }, 0);
```